# Hide Pro-Forma Invoices to Employees in the Accounting Module Odoo 10.0

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

While using Odoo 10.0 (Or Odoo 9) How can I hide pro-forma invoices under the accounting module to a specific group/user? I'm trying to hide the records that show when you click Customer Invoices (Under Accounting > Sales > Customer Invoices) if it's in the proforma state.

For example: The business manager would see the following:

CUSTOMER  |  STATUS

Customer 1 |  Open

Customer 2 | Pro-forma

Customer 3 |  Paid

and the user would see

CUSTOMER  | STATUS

Customer 1 |  Open

Customer 3 |  Paid

This is for Odoo 10.0 under the Accounting/Invoice module.

Comment: you can define an access rule uder settings->security->access rule

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the record rule for that model to view the records for the group of users
Ex:

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="some_name">
            <field name="name">Name of the record rule</field>
            <field name="model_id" ref="model_(your_model_name)"/>
            <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('group_name'))]"/>
            <field eval="0" name="perm_unlink"/>
            <field eval="0" name="perm_write"/>
            <field eval="1" name="perm_read"/>
            <field eval="0" name="perm_create"/>
            <field name="domain_force">[('user_id','=',user.id), ('state','=','your_state')]</field>
</record>
```

By this way you can give the access permission to view the records for the group of users.

I think it could helps to you

Answer (score 0):

Go to  the setting of the sale module and uncheck the pro-forma invoice field.

Hope this will help you.